# iOS 10 face recognition - Merge people?

Tags: photos, ios, photos.app

My photo app shows two separate sets of the same person, but iOS thinks they are different people, even if the name is the same. Is there any way I can manually "merge" two separate people?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, found it: in the Photos app...
- go to "People"
- Click on "Select" in the upper right corner of the screen
- Then click on the "Merge" button in the lower right corner of the screen.